# get the ID of last DIV inside a DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below.

```
<div id=container>
    <div id=box1></div>
    <div id=box2></div>
    <div id=box3></div>
    <div id=box4></div>
    <div id=box5></div>
    <div id=box6></div>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to get the id of the last div inside container using jQuery?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try this:

***jQuery Code***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#container').children().last().attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
var id = $('#container div:last').attr('id')
```

Comment: is there any reason i would be getting response 'undefined'

Answer (score 6):

Well you can do this:

```
$("#container div").last().attr("id")
```

Or if you only want to include divs that are direct children of `#container` (assuming your real-world code has more elements and might have divs inside the divs) change the above selector to `"#container > div"`.

But note that there's no one "correct" way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.last()` method which will help you to match the last element.

You can then get the `id`

```
$('#container div').last().attr('id');
```

**[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CNzdj/)**.

**[More on jquery .last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)**